# ¿Como hago para que mi programa no haga trampa?

Tags: java, visual-studio, string, bucle-for, estructuras-de-datos

Hola tengo un problema y es que no se como implementar que mi programa detecta cuando le hacen trampa así, que puedo hacer mira mi problema:

elabora un juego que adivina un número de 0 a 100.

El programa pregunta si el número es 50 inicialmente y si el usuario le dice que es +, - o = se espera que de forma óptima el juego es capaz de adivinar un número que piensa un usuario. La salida debe ser similar a la siguiente (se asume que el programa propone un número y el usuario digita +, - o = dependiendo del número que pensó)

Esta es la entrada de datos:

[image: esta es la entrada de datos]

Aquí esta mi Código, si alguien me puede ayudar estaría genial gracias

```
 public class Adivinar {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    randomNumber(0, 100, 50);
}

public static void randomNumber(int limiteInferior, int limiteSuperior, int numeroPregunta) throws IOException {

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("es " + numeroPregunta + "?");
    String signo = br.readLine();
    if (signo.equalsIgnoreCase("+")) {
        limiteInferior = numeroPregunta;
        numeroPregunta = (limiteInferior + limiteSuperior) / 2;

        randomNumber(limiteInferior, limiteSuperior, numeroPregunta);
        
    } else if (signo.equalsIgnoreCase("-")) {
        limiteSuperior = numeroPregunta;
        numeroPregunta = (limiteInferior + limiteSuperior) / 2;

        randomNumber(limiteInferior, limiteSuperior, numeroPregunta);
    } else if (signo.equalsIgnoreCase("=")) {
        
        System.out.println("yuju!" + numeroPregunta );
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Hola, el problema es que al llamarse la funcion `randomNumber()` de nuevo, se vuelve a declarar la variable `numeroPregunta` y se le asigna el valor `50`. Estas utilizando una especie de recursion que no está del todo bien. Te aconsejo que leas sobre recursion https://www.programiz.com/java-programming/recursion o que utilizes un bucle iterativo para simplificar las cosas. Por otro lado, el cálculo de `numeroPregunta` no creo que sea correcto, ya que `(limiteInferior + limiteSuperior) / 2`siempre será igual a 50

Comment: hola, mira ya arregle mi codigo ahora necesito ayuda como haria para que mi programa no haga trampa?

Comment: Antes que nada, una pequeña correcion, en tu metodo `main()` en vez de hacer `randomNumber(); ` deberías tener `randomNumber(0, 100, 50);` Supongo que te faltó editarlo. Ahora con respecto a "que mi programa no haga trampa?" vas a tener que detallar un poco mas a qué te refieres con que tu programa haga trampa. Porque no estoy seguro que es lo que seria hacer trampa

Comment: digamos le paso es 50 si "+" , es 75 no "-", es 62 no "-" , es 56 no "-", 53no, 51no, entonces debe ser 50 esto es cuando me refiero a trampa como haria para resolver esto

Comment: Pero en ese caso el programa no estaría haciendo trampa, el que haría trampa sería el usuario. Se me ocurre que podrías identificar ese caso cuando los limites superior e inferior coincidan o esten muy cerca. Intenta eso, si no puedes trataré de programarlo esta noche

Comment: la verdad no pude programarlo, sera que me podria ayudar please

Comment: Pero que intentaste?

Comment: Algo como if límiteInferior > númeroPregunta y númeroPregunta <limiteSuperior pero la verdad no se me ocurre nada mas para solucionar esa parte

Comment: El algoritmo que usas es el de búsqueda binaria (https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%BAsqueda_binaria) te aconsejo que leas sobre arboles binarios (https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%81rbol_binario) De esta manera irias recortando el arbol hasta dar con el numero del usuario y detectar si hizo trampa, se me ocurre que si llegaste a una hoja del árbol y el user no puso "=" podrias considerar que hizo trampa. Pero deberías pensarlo un poco mas. Te dejo esos recursos para que te encamines en una posible solución. PD: Los arboles binarios pueden construirse por medio de arreglos (busca eso tambien)